# MySql cutting off last number

Tags: mysql, sql

Sorry for asking but I'm trying to get last 10 numbers from this result    "219916#54         /0004112986"

Main criteria i used for that is SUBSTR(TRENN,-11,10) so i get only last 10 numbers.. Query I'm using is :

```
$sqlQuery = "SELECT b.NR_LE, b.NR_VP_EXTERN, b.PN FROM (SELECT DISTINCT NR_LE_1 FROM table WHERE lager = 'RA1' AND ID_KLIENT = 'IACTVK' AND ID_ARTIKEL <> 'VERSAND' AND MNG_FREI > 0 
AND NOT ((ORT ='STD' AND BEREICH ='WV') OR (ORT ='INV' AND BEREICH ='YV' AND PLATZ ='99'))) a,
(SELECT DISTINCT NR_LE, NR_VP_EXTERN, **SUBSTR(TRENN,-11,10)** AS PN FROM table WHERE NR_VP_EXTERN IS NOT NULL) b
WHERE a.NR_LE_1 = b.NR_LE 
ORDER BY b.NR_LE, b.NR_VP_EXTERN";
```

But somehow im getting result with "/" ... like "/000411298" so last number is cut off and instead there comes "/" in front and i dont know anymore how to take only last 10 numbers without the "/" in front that come there from nowhere..

So the result with upper query is :

```
NR_LE   "53638786"
NR_VP_EXTERN    "12FR03792"
PN     "/000411298"
```

And i need it like :

```
NR_LE   "53638786"
NR_VP_EXTERN    "12FR03792"
PN     "0004112986"
```

Thank you for help

Comment: How about change to `SUBSTRING_INDEX(TRENN,'/',-1)` ?

Comment: Why `-11` ... seems like you are going 1 char to far to the left

Comment: By the way Tom, is it going to be always 10 digit length at the end that you're looking for? or there are other lengths?

Comment: @GetSet Seems like it.. thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can use `right()` like `RIGHT(TRENN,10)`

And also it's always best to use join explicitly

```
SELECT b.NR_LE, b.NR_VP_EXTERN, b.PN FROM 
(
SELECT DISTINCT NR_LE_1 FROM table 
WHERE lager = 'RA1' AND ID_KLIENT = 'IACTVK' AND ID_ARTIKEL <> 'VERSAND' AND MNG_FREI > 0 
AND NOT ((ORT ='STD' AND BEREICH ='WV') OR (ORT ='INV' AND BEREICH ='YV' AND PLATZ ='99'))
) a inner join 
(SELECT DISTINCT NR_LE, NR_VP_EXTERN, RIGHT(TRENN,10) AS PN FROM table WHERE NR_VP_EXTERN IS NOT NULL
) b on a.NR_LE_1 = b.NR_LE 
ORDER BY b.NR_LE, b.NR_VP_EXTERN
```

Comment: This is also the faster way of doing it rather than using PHP to make the changes.